# matlab point cloud - no polygon/face representation?

Tags: matlab, polygon, face, ply-file-format

I have a short question concerning matlab's representation of point clouds. I am importing a point cloud from a **.ply file**, which contains vertex-, vertex normal- and face information, i.e., **it is explicitly stored in the file which points form triangles together.** However, when I read said .ply file using **pcread**, the resulting point cloud contains vertex and vertex normal information, **but no face/polygon information**; I would have expected that the point cloud - object contains some form of, for instance, an adjacency matrix which shows which points are connected to which other points.

So my question: do I really have to compute - on the fly - a triangulation from the points in the point cloud in matlab? As far as I'm aware, I have no guarantee that the faces I end up with are the same faces that are encoded in the original .ply file - or do I?

Comment: I used [this FEX](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5355-toolbox-graph/content/toolbox_graph/read_ply.m) in the past to overcome this problem